# Lookup with .left and .offset

Tags: excel, vba

In the code below, I look for empty cells in `cRange`. Each empty cell should be filled with a value based on a VLOOKUP. The value I am looking up in `rngLookup` is the first five characters of the string immediately to the left of `cRange.Cells(x)`.

The macro is throwing a "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error for the line with the VLOOKUP formula. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my syntax. Please help.

```
Dim rngLookup As Range
Set rngLookup = Sheets("Account Descriptions").Range("A2:B468")

LastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("B6").End(xlDown).Row
Set cRange = Sheets("Summary").Range("F6:F" & LastRow)
For x = cRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With cRange.Cells(x)
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
            .Formula = Application.vLookup(rngLookup, .Left(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), 5), 2, False)
        End If
    End With
Next x
```

Comment: The first argument in VLOOKUP is a single value.  Try swapping your `rngLookup` and `.Left(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), 5)` around.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - except `.Left` should be `Left`, and the `ActiveCell` should be dropped.

Comment: @BigBen  lol, yep.... getting late in the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your argument order is off: lookup value first, lookup range second.
- [`.Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.left) is a property of the range; you want the [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) function.
- You're writing a value, not a formula, so use `.Value`.
- Don't use `ActiveCell`.

```
.Value = Application.Vlookup(Left(.Offset(,-1).Value, 5), rngLookup, 2, False)
```